# woocomerce get list of product of curent categury by two taxonomy

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to get the list of product in a current category that they have checked by two taxonomy brand id = 20 and usability id = 26

```html
<?php
    $args = array(
                    'post_type' => array('post','product'),
                    'tax_query' => array(
                          'relation' => 'OR',
                       array(
                         'taxonomy' => 'brand',
                         'field' => 'id',
                         'terms' => 26,
                       ),
                       array(
                         'taxonomy' => 'useability',
                         'terms' => 25,
                         'field' => 'id'
                       ),
                       
        
                    )
                );
              
                $vv = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```

Comment: can you add more details for what you have tried, sample code, etc? there arent a lot of details to help.

Comment: I want to list my product in category book that this product must have two custom taxonomy as brand and usability checked